# releasing turbogears2 handle on specific DB (controlling the transaction manager)

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, turbogears2

I'm building a turbogears application that works with 2 db - the second one - which I'm referring to is an mssql db - used by another application (not mine - my application is actually a hack to solve a problem - so I can't control the other application or the mssql db settings)

I'm writing to a specific db table with sqlalchemy (through turbogears) using:

```
 DBSession.add(object)
 DBSession.flush()
```

the data is written to the db - but the turbogears application retains some sort of handle on the db, so the main applicaion using that db table can read from it but can't change it. until I stop the turbogears application and then everything works.
I tried to call:

```
DBSession.close()
```

but then the data was magically removed from the db - probably a transaction rollback.
I also tried to call:

```
transaction.doom()
```

with similiar effects (or no effect at all I'm not sure)

I read that in turbogears the transaction manager (I guess repoze.tm) handles the commits
but I can't figure - when is it called? how do I control it? and especially how to remove the db handle when the function finished it's scheduled run (I can't just end the script, it's a cron job, running every hour). the tg2.1 docs is very unclear on this subject

I also read somewhere I should override the commit_veto - but didn't understand - how should I do it and where? and where in my application I should call the transaction.abort() .doom() or whatever?

I also tried the same functions using transaction hooks but didn't succeed to actually call the hook

thanks for any help.

version data:

- turbogears 2.1.3
- sqlalchemy 0.7
- mssql 2005
- using pyodbc to connect to mssql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DBSession.flush()` executes SQL, but doesn't commit. You have to call `DBSession.commit()` to finish transaction (not need to explicitly call `flush()` in this case, `commit()` will do it). After `commit()` SQLAlchemy starts new transaction, but this shouldn't be a problem since data is usually locked only when you execute some SQL statement.

Comment: I'll accept although I found out the problem is a little different - tg2 handles the commits with a transaction manager based on repoze.tm so actually calling DBSession.commit() gives an error message and you should really call transaction.commit()